# How to add .env files in auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe, .env

How do you use `auto-py-to-exe`'s -onefile and add a `.env`?

I'm programming a python app that has API Key and I'm wondering how you can add a `.env` file to `auto-py-to-exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `--add-data` or "Additional files" feature in `auto-py-to-exe` and add a file to the root directory which you can do by adding a period (`.`) to the file directory (the root directory is the directory, in which your py file is in the exe)

[image: see here an example]

EDIT:

The user can not see the content neither of the python file nor of the env file, because this is then an exe file, and you can not convert exe files back to their original format. You could also inplement the API Key in the python file, the user isn't able to get the Key out of the exe file

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can the file be read by other users? i know its a .env, but couldn't it just be opened by the other users?

Comment: Nope, because this is then an exe file, and you can not convert exe files back to their original format. You could also inplement the API Key in the python file, the user isn't able to get the Key out of the exe file

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, but im pretty sure theres many programs that can decompile the exe program back to a readable python file. i wondering if i should obfuscate it?

Comment: You could theoretically try to decompile an exe, but it would be very, very, very inaccurate because an executable application is wrote in binary / hex and an python file in text

Comment: sure, but what do you recommend me to use: `onedir` or `onefile` thanks a lot

Comment: onefile, you don't want to have the exe file in an directory with like 10 more files and 10 more folders, do you? onefile compresses all the files in one

Comment: Can we have a readable .env file. meaning can it be outside the exe file and may be in the same folder level. So that any changes to .env file can be done without having to re-create the exe ? Is this possible ? Please reply.

Comment: Hi, yes, I think you can change the path of the file in your code to for example ``C:\some\path\to\file.env``.